# How to set a breakpoint on an event?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, javascript-debugger

How do I force a breakpoint in JavaScript code on event (i.e. on button click) ?

I am using Google Chrome.

Are there any browser compatibility issues that might come with it?

Comment: Look in Developer Tools (if you havn't already). Control + Shift + I. Go to sources. Select your javaScript file you want. 'Add breakpoint' will be on the right hand side.

Comment: Sorry, i meant in the code

Comment: Please take time to search SO before posting your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up a button click listener and call the `debugger;`

**Example**

```
$("#myBtn").click(function() {
 debugger;   
});
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/hBCH5/

**Resources on debugging in JavaScript**

- http://www.laurencegellert.com/2012/05/the-three-ways-of-setting-breakpoints-in-javascript/
- http://berzniz.com/post/78260747646/5-javascript-debugging-tips-youll-start-using-today